# Checkbox Populate Form Fields

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, populate, auto-populate

I wish to use a checkbox to populate form fields.

**Example User Flow:**
Visitor fills out shipping info fields like name, address, zip, city.
Visitor has option to checkbox to auto populate billing info fields.
If user checks "same as billing info" checkbox, the shipping info fields
with input data are copy / pasted into billing info fields.

Please visit: http://staelements.com/register

[image: Dynamic Populate Checkbox Auto Form Copy Paste Field]

Is J$ is best way to achive this?
Please tell me if there is a better solution.
Thanks for your attention good citizen!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use Jquery to achive this .. first load the propery jquery library to your project or page ..

then if your checkbox is like this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />

<!-- account form fields  -->
<input type="text" id="name" />
<input type="text" id="phone" />

<!-- billing form fields-->
<input type="text" id="name_billing" />
<input type="text" id="phone_billing" />

$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#checkbox1").change(function() {
  if(this.checked) {
   alert("checked ");
    //get the values of the filled fields
    $name = $("#name").val();
    $phone = $("#phone").val();
    console.log("name");
    // then add those values to your billing infor window feilds 

    $("#name_billing").val($name);
    $("#phone_billing").val($phone);

    // then form will be automatically filled .. 

  }
  else{
   $('#name_billing').val('');
   $("#phone_billing").val('');
  }
 });
});
```

check the js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2kt0usfx/

if you want to remove the values when uncheck , just

I did not test this , but hope this will work for you

Comment: Using firebug, I see the script is being loaded. I'm focusing on just copying "Your Name" to billing info "name" on checkbox check. With your code layout, I understand, but it's not working. Thanks for the attempt!! Your awesome!

Comment: did you load the proper jquery library to your project .. 

then check wether event is working by adding alert & please add $(document).ready(function(){ code I have give  });

check the edit

Comment: Your example is perfect! My WordPress powered site is loading jQuery v1.11.0 and I've assigned proper ID to input but still broken! If you visit my link above, you may confirm everything you typed is being loaded. Thanks again

Comment: in js fiddle as you can see , I have loaded the jQuery 1.11.0 , is the alert coming ? ? what about fire bug console ? ? is it showing the values of the name value ( console.log($name);) 

& if you are satisfied with the answer please rate it .. thanks

Comment: Outside of CF7 it works great! Using CF7 though, doesn't - and I don't understand. Contact Form 7 plugin is giving me problems. I posted this thread - http://wordpress.org/support/topic/j-not-loading-checkbox-populate-form-field-worksbut-not-with-cf7